# XNA and PhysX : Error Loading Pipeline Assembly C:\...\Game\eyecm.PhysX

Tags: xna

I have the physx sdk and runtime installed, but for some reason, I keep getting that error message when I try to build my game. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the filename of the missing assembly, you'll need to install the [PhysX Candy Wrapper (eyecm)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/eyecm-physx/). Make sure you download the XNA-specific binaries. PhysX is written in native code, so a wrapper is necessary to use it from managed code.